# Doesn't understand why this error appeared

Tags: python

Hello I'm resolving a little exercise for school everything was good but I just got this error when I test the program:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\couco\OneDrive\Bureau\puissance4.py", line 17, in test
    assert isWinInARow([[],[],[],[],[],[]],0,0)==False
  File "C:\Users\couco\OneDrive\Bureau\puissance4.py", line 10, in isWinInARow
    if g[i+h][j] != g[i][j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand what it means so but even by running the program by hand (;-;) I didn't solve my problem. Can you help me Thank You <3

The code:

```
# Créé par couco, le 06/01/2022 en Python 3.7
def isWinInALine(g,i,j):
    for k in range(4):
        if g[i][j+k] != g[i][j]:
            return False
    return True

def isWinInARow(g,i,j):
    for h in range(4):
        if g[i+h][j] != g[i][j]:
            return False
    return True

def test():
    assert isWinInALine([[1,1,1,1,],[],[],[],[],[]],0,0)==True
    assert isWinInALine([[1,0,1,1,],[],[],[],[],[]],0,0)==False
    assert isWinInARow([[],[],[],[],[],[]],0,0)==False
    assert isWinInARow([[1],[1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1],[]],0,0)==True
    assert isWinInARow([[1],[0,1],[1,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1],[]],0,0)==False
```

Comment: It means that I+h is greater than the length of the array.

Comment: @2pichar Or that I+h <0 but I already know that but it doesn't happend in the test

Comment: you have to run the test() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because you are accessing the 0th element of an empty list. An empty list has no elements, and so it is an out of bounds access to the list.

```py
def isWinInALine(g,i,j):
    for k in range(4):
        if g[i][j+k] != g[i][j]:
            return False
    return True

def isWinInARow(g,i,j):
    print(len(g))
    print(i, j)
    for h in range(4):
        print(i + h)
        print(g[i+h])
        if g[i+h][j] != g[i][j]:
            return False
    return True

def test():
    #print(isWinInALine([[1,1,1,1,],[],[],[],[],[]],0,0)==True)
    #print(isWinInALine([[1,0,1,1,],[],[],[],[],[]],0,0)==False)
    print(isWinInARow([[None],[None],[None],[None],[None],[None]],0,0)==False) #this fixes the error by adding an element to each list
    #print(isWinInARow([[1],[1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1],[]],0,0)==True)
    #print(isWinInARow([[1],[0,1],[1,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1],[]],0,0)==False)
test()
```